# Typescript convert const array of objects to typed index lookup object

Tags: typescript

```
const cars = [
  { id: 'id1', name: 'ford' },
  { id: 'id2', name: 'audi' },
  { id: 'id3', name: 'bmw' },
] as const;
type CarId = typeof cars[number]['id'];

const carIndexes = cars.reduce((acc, car, i) => ({ ...acc, [car.id]: i }), {});
console.log(carIndexes);
```

This code works fine, and prints out

```
{ id1: 0, id2: 1, id3: 2 }
```

`carIndexes` gives me a map that allows me to look up the index of each car by their `id`, but I would like `carIndexes` to be strongly typed. When I change its type signature to `{ [K in CarId]: number }`:

```
const carIndexes: { [K in CarId]: number } = cars.reduce((acc, car, i) => ({ ...acc, [car.id]: i }), {});
```

I get the error:

```
error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ id1: number; id2: number; id3: number; }': id1, id2, id3
```

I would like to use a plain object, rather than a `Map`, because an object with type `{ [K in CarId]: number }` guarantees that looking up the index can't fail for any `CarId`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, without casting manually to `{[K in CarId]: number}`, there is no way for typescript to detect that `cars.reduce((acc, car, i) => ({ ...acc, [car.id]: i }), {})` (or other ways) will return an object with the whole CardId as index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to explicitly type the reduce accumulator value:

```
const cars = [
    { id: 'id1', name: 'ford' },
    { id: 'id2', name: 'audi' },
    { id: 'id3', name: 'bmw' },
] as const;
type CarId = typeof cars[number]['id'];

const carIndexes = cars
    .reduce(
        (acc, car, i) => (
            { ...acc, [car.id]: i }
        ),
        {} as { [K in CarId]: number }
    );
console.log(carIndexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best attempt at type safety in this case might be to use corresponding **Partial** type:

```
let carIndexes: Partial<{ [key in CarId]: number }> = {};
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i) {
  carIndexes[cars[i].id] = i;
  
  // note that following line would not compile due to TS2339: Property 'OTHER_PROPERTY' does not 
  // exist on type 'Partial<{ id1: number; id2: number; id3: number; }>'
  // carIndexes.OTHER_PROPERTY = 0;
}
```

The use of **reduce()** function proposed by some other answers and involving an explicit cast, in fact, ensures almost no static type safety. For instance, if I make a typo like following, the code still compiles:

```
const carIndexes: { [K in CarId]: number } = cars.reduce(
  (acc, car, i) => ({ 
    ...acc,
    //following line should not compile as there is no property "id" on typeof carIndexes
    id: i 
  }),
  {} as {[K in CarId]: number}
);
```